# Bootstrap Navbar Issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

On a site I am working on, the background on the navbar works fine when expanded, but on the collapsed view, the button does not open the navbar. Below is the code I am using for the navbar. Please let me know if you have any ideas on why this may be happening. Thanks!

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
<div class="container-fluid">
<!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
<div class="navbar-header">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img src="http://entropymag.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/outer-space-wallpaper-pictures.jpg" height="25" width="40"></a>
</div>

<!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">


  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-center">
    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="resume.html">Skills</a></li> 

  </ul>
</div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Comment: From the code you've shown, I do not see an issue - https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/19449/

Answer (score 0):

You must have left out bootstrap.js

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like jlemm45 suggested... do this

[image: Like Jlemm45 suggested do this]

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things that could be the issue the first being that you need to include bootstrap's javascript file like the other answers suggest.  Then next is that in order for bootstrap's javascript to work you need to include jquery.  Then next is that you need to load jquery's javascript library before you include bootstrap's javascript.  So all that being said your navbar code looks correct so it must be one of these issues.  So like I said you need to include jquery and bootstraps javascript and you need to load jquery first.  So it should look something like the following.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified Jquery JavaScript This needs to be before bootstraps javascript -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified Bootstrap JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head>
  <body> 
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container-fluid">
      <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img src="http://entropymag.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/outer-space-wallpaper-pictures.jpg" height="25" width="40"></a>
      </div>

      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">


        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-center">
          <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
          <li><a href="resume.html">Skills</a></li> 

        </ul>
      </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
      </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
  </body> 
</html>
```

You can link to your css and javascript files locally or you can use the cdn's like I have above but I figured I would use the cdn's so you can copy and paste this code and see it working.  Hopefully this helps.